# Monte Carlo multiprocessing TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a multiprocessed version of Monte Carlo Pi calculation.

However, I always get an error that says

> TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'

I read that the error can be fixed by using starmap but it doesn't work either for some reason.

```
%%timeit
import random
import math
import itertools
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import functools

def monteCarlo(total):
    inside = 0
    for i in range(0, total):
        x2 = random.random()**2
        y2 = random.random()**2
        if math.sqrt(x2 + y2) < 1.0:
            inside += 1

    pi = (float(inside) / total) * 4
    return pi

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    values = [100]
    data = sum(pool.map(functools.partial(monteCarlo, values)))
    print(data)
```

Comment: `pool.map` requires two arguments: `func`, and `iterable`. You are passing only one argument: `functools.partial(monteCarlo, values)`. Did you mean `pool.map(monteCarlo, values)`?

Comment: Yes. The "functools.partial" was to fix another error with the scope, that i had. But i get the same error without it.

Comment: You cannot get the same error because then you would pass two arguments and the `iterable` argument would not be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to call partial to get map value partial rather use just `pool.map`. The `partial()` is used for partial function application which “freezes” some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with a simplified signature. But you don't have need something `freeze`, if further need to use partial then you need to pass two argument to get the callable beahave. Get more about [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
import random
import math
import itertools
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import functools

def monteCarlo(total):
    inside = 0
    for i in range(0, total):
        x2 = random.random()**2
        y2 = random.random()**2
        if math.sqrt(x2 + y2) < 1.0:
            inside += 1

    pi = (float(inside) / total) * 4
    return pi

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    values = [100]
    data = sum(pool.map(monteCarlo, values))
    print(data)
```

Comment: thx dude, now i know it has something to do with timeit and with not my pool.map